# Async Null check inside a template for angular dart

Tags: angular-dart

Morning,

I cannot figure out how to do this in angular dart.  In typescript angular it looks like you can go: 
`<div *ngIf="club | async as club"> </div>`
but the 'as' operator does not work in dart.

I tried something like:
`<div *ngIf="(club | async) != null"> </div>`

I also tried to do a bound template variable but the syntax there seemed to be am issue too.
`<template #realclub="club | async"><club-details [club]="realclub"></club-details></template>`

Any idea how I can handle a null check with an async value inside the html syntax for angular dart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand your question, but you can make it into a dart function and call it from your angular html. It would be something like this

`var club = await clubFuture();
if (club == null) club = realClub;`

where you can simplify using the null-aware operator like

`var club = (await clubFuture()) ?? realClub;`